# message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'gag_id' cannot be null

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade, select2

Dentro de mi formulario tengo una sección en la cual utilizo Ajax para traer y autocompletar campos de manera dinamica dependiendo de la opcion seleccionada desde mi select.
El punto es el siguiente:
Cuando utilizo el formulario para crear un nuevo registro,  desde el select selecciono una opcion(numero de mordaza) y mediante este se autocompletan los campos necesarios, al crear un nuevo registro no hay problema.
Ahora al editar ese mismo registro recientemente creado, si actualizo cualquier otro campo que no sea el select(numero de mordaza), arroja un error de validacion como el siguiente:

**> message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'gag_id' cannot be null**

[image: Select número de mordaza]

Como pueden observar en la imagen,  recupero el numero de mordaza que ya ha sido seleccionado anteriormente, pero de alguna manera no esta tomando el valor

para evitar ese error, tengo que volver a seleccionar el numero de mordaza, y recién ahí puedo actualizar.

existe una manera para que al editar, no me arroje ese error y no tenga que volver a selcccionar el mismo numero de mordaza?

inspeccionado con: dd($request->all()); recibo esto por consola: **("number_gag" => null)**

```
array:18 [
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "_token" => "vWKsZ2HBk8bzim6qLOm05JkBGdcrQY5vXKhlotYb"
  "order_id" => "2"
  "code" => "0112-0112-0/4"
  "part_piece" => "1"
  "user" => "Luis"
  "machine_id" => "1"
  "category_maq" => "TORNO"
  "name_program" => "0112-0112-0/4"
  "number_program" => "1001"
  "part_program" => "1"
  "tools" => array:3 [
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "3"
  ]
  "number_gag" => null
  "diameter" => "24"
  "type_gag" => "EXTERIOR"
  "category_gag" => "PASANTE"
  "time" => "0:01:30"
  "observation" => null
]
```

**Editado:**

Aca en mi metodo create lleno mi select con los numero de mordazas existentes:

```
 public function create()
    {
        $piece = new Piece(); 
        
        $this->authorize('create', $piece);
                           
        return view('admin.pieces.partials.form', [        
       
            'number_gag'    => Gag::pluck('number_gag', 'id'),    
            'piece'         => $piece
        ]);       
    }
```

Con esto realizo una consulta para luego traer mediante Ajax los datos que deseo y asi auto-completar los campos:

```
public function showGag(Request $request, $id)
    {   
        $gags = Gag::findOrFail($id);       
             
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            return $gags->toJson();
        }  

        return response()->json(['message' => 'recibimos el request pero no es ajax']);
    }
```

Aca utilizo Ajax:

```
 var number_gagSelect = $('#number_gag');            
            var diameter = $('#diameter');    
            var type_gag = $('#type_gag');    
            var category_gag = $('#category_gag');   
            var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');    
           
            number_gagSelect.on('change', function() {                
                var id = $(this).val();               
                obtenerDetalleDeGag(id)               
            }); 
            
            function obtenerDetalleDeGag(id) {
                $.ajax({                  
                    url: '/admin/pieces/showGag/' + id,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {            
                        '_token': csrf_token
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {

                        console.log(response);   
                                      
                        llenarInputs(response);
                    },
                    error: function () { 
                        console.log(error);
                        alert('Hubo un error obteniendo el detalle del legajo!');
                    }
                })
            }
           
            function llenarInputs(data) {                
                diameter.val(data.diameter);     
                type_gag.val(data.type_gag);     
                category_gag.val(data.category_gag);                            
            }
```

Este es mi formulario sección select

```
<div class="form-group">                    
                    {!! Form::label('number_gag', 'Número de mordaza:') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        </div>        
                        {!! Form::select('number_gag', $number_gag, $piece->gag_id, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'number_gag', 'placeholder' => '',  'style' => 'width:100%;']) !!}                     
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: @BetaM actualice mi pregunta podrias revisarla? inclui mi metodo create en cual realizo un pluck para llenar el select y tambien inclui el metodo showGag con el cual paso los valores a mi llamada ajax

Comment: @BetaM alguna opción para que al editar la opción se marque como seleccionada?